# Azure AD OpenID login not showing errors on fail

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid

I have been updating a system that has been in place for sometime and finding some clients have issues with login on mobile devices.

I have a test system in place and setup Application in Azure AD and noticed during testing if I login with incorrect credentials, login.microsoftonline.com will show:

> Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
>   AADSTS50020: User account...

When login to the clients live systems I don't see this error and just get returned to the home page of the application.

The only difference is the client apps are configured with credentials for there Azure AD instance and I cannot access them. These where also built on the legacy App Registrations but that shouldn't be issue (ha).  The server side is the same implementation.

Why am I not seeing the AADSTS errors in productions sites?

Comment: Can you add more detail? if this is a custom application. Can you share snippets and implementation detail?

Comment: Not sure for what purpose, in relation to sharing snippets? The code is not the issue as it is the same across all deployments. 
I am interested in any possible configurations that are known to prevent the error messages as they come from Azure not my application. Azure is either showing the error or just forwarding back to the app.
My only clue at this time is the production deployments are behind cloud flare so perhaps that is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not seeing any error and are just getting returned to the homepage it seems more likely to be an issue with the Redirect URI or the app registration configuration.

Please confirm that the redirect URIs in your application and in your registration are what they are intended be.

Also, ask them to check the developer tool logs when signing in to see if anything shows up. It might be failing but not triggering the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the info Marilee, that was the only part I could not test myself being out of my control.
Could you elaborate on the developer tool logs please? Are they located in the Azure AD portal or you referring to the Browser developer tool ? 
I am requesting the clients provide the Sign-up logs in Azure AD for comparison